# Return Data based on Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am modifying a current query which returns n amount of rows. I would need to return the same amount of rows but with one more column of data.

I have two sql tables shown below. Products and Product Attribute Values.
When i run this query

```
SELECT * FROM  dbo.Product WHERE DealerRowId = '10'
```

i get a few 1000 rows back.
But when i run this query

```
SELECT * FROM Product p
inner JOIN ProductAttributeValues pav ON pav.SerialNo = p.SerialNo
WHERE (p.DealerRowId = '10') and pav.Name = 'sequence'
```

I get back less rows.

My question is how would i get back all the rows from the products table that match the DealerRowId and any rows from the Product Attribute Value tables that match on serial no, i would expect that any product that does not have a serial to return null.

[image]

Comment: You have a more restrictive `where` condition.  Why are the results surprising?

Comment: @GordonLinoff i am modifying a current query which returns n amount of rows. I would need to return the same amount of rows but with one more column of data.

Comment: @Abra left join won't work. I'm not sure if joins will work.

Comment: You are exactly describing a left outer join from product to productattributevalues. Simply add your constraint on pav.name to the on clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to move the condition on the second table to the `on` caluse:

```
SELECT *
FROM Product p LEFT JOIN
     ProductAttributeValues pav
     ON pav.SerialNo = p.SerialNo AND pav.Name = 'sequence'
WHERE p.DealerRowId = '10';
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want

SELECT * FROM Product p
inner JOIN ProductAttributeValues pav ON pav.SerialNo = p.SerialNo
WHERE (p.DealerRowId = '10') AND pav.SerialNo IS NOT NULL

Does this solves your problem. Also, why are you using pav.Name = 'sequence' in where.
You can try it in the ON clause if you want to join your columns based on names.

Comment: Thanks, the ProductAttributeValues can have multiple serial no's that have a different names  'sequence' is the value in the name column that i would need.